# Prevent SQL view from being blocked by lengthy delete/insert transaction using snapshot isolation

Tags: sql-server, view, transactions

I am attempting to prevent "splash pages" on our website, which are generated from SQL views, from blocking during the rather lengthy update of underlying tables.

The update stored procedure utilizes `snapshot` isolation and the resulting `row versioning` allows transacted `select` queries from the tables being updated; returning their values prior to the updating transaction beginning.  Wonderful stuff.

Unfortunately, my `select` queries still appear to be blocked if they are from a `view` constructed from the underlying tables.

UPDATE: Turns out these queries are not blocked in the traditional sense as there are no requests in `WAIT` state in `sys.dm_tran_locks`.  But are none-the-less stalled waiting for synchronous statistics to complete before compiling.

Thank you, @Charlieface for exposing this essential piece to using `SNAPSHOT` isolation for data availability during large update transactions!

Comment: Are you using `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` at the database level, or are you using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT`? Perhaps there is a *more* restrictive hint somewhere, such as `SERIALIZABLE/HOLDLOCK/REPEATABLE READ`

Comment: I am using only `STILS` now.  I had `RCSI` enabled initially on our test DB but disabled it - I don't want to use it going forward as it would affect the default isolation for all transactions.   Likewise, I have not used `HINTS` in any queries or view definitions as most documentation suggests avoiding them unless absolutely necessary.  But I would consider using hints in this case if it would solve this problem.

Comment: What happens if you use a `READ COMMITTED` hint on the view (in the outer query)?

Comment: The `SELECT` query is blocked by the update.

Comment: In another query window, can you run the following while the blocking is happening `select resource_type, request_mode from sys.dm_exec_tran_locks where request_status = 'WAIT'` and tell us the result

Comment: `select resource_type,request_mode
from sys.dm_tran_locks
where request_status = 'WAIT'` returns nothing

Comment: Hmmm I would have expected that to show something. Maybe try this page, which has a very good script to identify the blocking chain https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/04/20/sql-server-blocking-tree-identifying-blocking-chain-using-sql-scripts/. You need to run it while the blocking is happening. Ultimately, if there is no blocking chain then it is probably *not* the `UPDATE` which is blocking, it's just a slow query plan. Are you sure it is a blocking problem?

Comment: At this point, I am pretty certain it is NOT a block in the classic sense: there are no `WAIT`s.  But it is a resource conflict of some sort - my guess is the indices - that is stalling my second transaction.  Looks as though `SNAPSHOT` transaction isolation and row versioning is not the panacea I was hoping for.

Comment: Are statistics updates set to asynchronous, they should be? Or perhaps you are getting a autogrowth, is your database large enough already? Do you have Instant File Initialization set to on?

Comment: Bingo!  `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS` was on but `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC` was off.  Second query is now returning.  Slow.  I still have some optimizing to do.  But this was definitely the missing piece.  @Charlie, if you could write this up as the answer, happy to give you the win.  It would be good if you could briefly explain what you lose when turning on ASYNC since it is not the default.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, after working through various options in the comments, that `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC` was set to `OFF`.

This meant that a big enough update was causing a synchronous statistics refresh, which in turn blocked other queries from even compiling.

If `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC` is set to `ON` then currently compiling queries do not benefit from the statistics update (a minor disadvantage), however there is no blocking because the statistics are refreshed asynchronously.

One more downside if it is `ON` is that you cannot access the database in single-user mode, although that case is obviously very rare, and you can just turn it off for that one time.

[See more in this great article,](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/leave-auto-update-statistics/) there are more very rare circumstances when you want it `OFF`

Comment: I have been reading the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-ver15#statistics-options) on the `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC`.  Their reasoning for it being off by default seems completely counter-intuitive to me.  I cannot see much downside and even if I find some, I can simply move the import tables to their own DB and turn it on there!  Thanks again, Charlie.